# Why would we want to have an Observable of a Specific Type

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular-observable

```
//declare observable
somenums: Observable<number[]>

//instantiate the oberservale
somenums: new Observable<number[]>(somefunc)
```

Why would I want to declare an observable with a specific type.
does having the observable as type number[] indicate that is observable will return an number[] to the observers?
how can data be streamed to the observable during instantiation and after instantiation?
and how will the observers process the stream in this scenario.

Comment: "*does having the observable as type number[] indicate that is observable will return an number[] to the observers?*" yes

Comment: how would you return a number[] in this scenario during instantiation and after instantiation. @VLAZ

Comment: It's not possible to produce value *during* initialisation. First the initialisation has to be done and *then* the observable can produce values. As for how to produce `number[]` simply do something like `subscriber.next([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Typing Observables

The type of an observable tells you the type of the object that is passed to the observer's `next` callback function. On top of this, Observables can emit either a `complete` or an `error` event (never both).

You type observables for the same reason you type an `Array`, or the return value of a `Function`. So that your IDE, interpreter, compiler, etc can help you ensure that your program does what you want it to.

#### Using Observables (basic)

```js
// declare observable
somenums: Observable<number[]>

// instantiate Observable 
// (from scratch)
somenums: new Observable<number[]>(observer => {
  observer.next([1,2,3]);
  observer.next([7,6,5]);
  observer.next([4,4,4]);
  observer.complete();
  return {
    unsubscribe: () => {/*do nothing*/}
  }
});

// instantiate the same observable 
// (from RxJS creation operator)
somenums: from([
  [1,2,3],
  [7,6,5],
  [4,4,4]
]);

// subscribe to observable, print emissions to the console
somenums.subscribe(console.log);

// Append the value 4 to each array of numbers, then print to the console
somenums.pipe(
  map(x => ([...x, 4]))
).subscribe(console.log);
```